# Low Disk Space on Volumn system "Root"

Tags: partition

I installed Debian 7 onto a one terabyte drive, I let Debian automatically setup partitions, also selected LVM, Then installed OwnCLoud. All was working fine until I receved the message Low Disk Space on Root, it is only 35mb free, I could no longer access the cloud storage,
Also Apache2 had to be restarted? which it started automaticaly. I can access the cloud after restarting Apache, But Cloud cannot access database? It must be that program cannot run due to space limitation. How can I increase this volume? I tired using Gpart live, but could not increase any volumes> Here is my fdisk -l listing!

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8de4adf7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63  2930272064  1465136001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00048b84

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          501758  1953523711   976510977    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5          501760  1953523711   976510976   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-root: 348 MB, 348127232 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 42 cylinders, total 679936 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-swap_1: 4273 MB, 4273995776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 519 cylinders, total 8347648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-usr: 8996 MB, 8996782080 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1093 cylinders, total 17571840 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-usr doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-var: 2998 MB, 2998927360 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364 cylinders, total 5857280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-var doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-tmp: 398 MB, 398458880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 48 cylinders, total 778240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-tmp doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-home: 982.9 GB, 982926753792 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 119500 cylinders, total 1919778816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/debian-home doesn't contain a valid partition table
root@debian:/home/dmsigala#
```

**Edit**

The output of `pvscan` and `df`:

```
root@debian:/home/dmsigala# pvscan
 PV /dev/sdb5 VG debian lvm2 [931.27 GiB / 0 free]
 Total: 1 [931.27 GiB] / in use: 1 [931.27 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0 ]

ot@debian:/home/dmsigala# df -h
 Filesystem               Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
 rootfs                   322M  294M  11M    97%   /
 /dev/mapper/debian-root  322M  294M  11M    97%   /
 /dev/sdb1                228M  17M   199M   8%    /boot
```

Comment: Can you give us your `df` output so we know what volumes are mounted where?

Comment: I would also like to see output of `pvscan`

Comment: @JoelDavis Do you really think that is unclear? ;-)

Comment: Yeah I do. I'm seeing one LV has the word "root" in it but it's unclear if this is the root filesystem of the OS or just the root of some other directory tree (like the DocumentRoot in apache httpd).

Comment: I am thinking that this question has been asked and answered several times.  Have you looked into the archives of this and SuperUser and ServerFault SEs prior to asking your question?

Comment: Joel, Im not up on all this for comments, the DF output is too many characters to add here? suggestion how to post DF,

Comment: root@debian:/home/dmsigala# pvscan
  PV /dev/sdb5   VG debian   lvm2 [931.27 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [931.27 GiB] / in use: 1 [931.27 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
root@debian:/home/dmsigala#

Comment: ot@debian:/home/dmsigala# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                   322M  294M   11M  97% /
udev                      10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    202M  672K  201M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/debian-root  322M  294M   11M  97% /
tmpfs                    5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                    404M  228K  404M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1                228M   17M  199M   8% /boot

Comment: Need help with psoting DF Output!

Comment: You should have edited your question instead.

Comment: @DennisSigala, I'm not seeing /home as being mounted anywhere in your df output. Did it get truncated due to the character limit in the comments? Basically, Hauke's suggestion is a good one, log out of any non-root user session, umount /home (if currently mount) shrink the /home volume, (mount again if needed) then expand the root filesystem, you should be able to do this without restarting.

Comment: To reduce a logical volume by 2 gigs: `lvreduce -r -L -2G <pathToLV>` to expand it by two gigs: `lvextend -r -L +2G <pathToLV>` You have to umount for the reduce but not for the extend (only ext3 and later, though)

Answer (score 1):

You should reduce the size of one of the other volumes. Probably there is much free space on `debian/home`; you could reduce it from 982.9 GB to e.g. 950 GiB in order to have some free space for flexibility. After you have reduced the filesystem (with `resize2fs` in case of ext3/ext4) you reduce the LV:

```
lvresize --size 950G debian/home
```

Then you can increase the root LV:

```
lvresize --size 1G debian/root
```

The last step is to resize the root volume file system (which may be possible after booting another system only).

Comment: I'll also mention that the `-r` option to lvresize is invaluable here, as shrinking volumes without first shrinking the filesystem can cause unrecoverable data loss. I'm extra paranoid so I also specify my resizes with the relative operations (plus and minus signs).

Comment: @JoelDavis If you save the output of `dmsetup table debian-home` in a safe place then you can easily get the missing capacity back. `lvresize` does not overwrite the data on disk. Neither will a failing mount (due to a too small device) destroy the file system.

Comment: Good to know, but I'm paranoid. So I'm still going to do the resize through the lvresize command, color me Oliver Stone I guess.

Comment: Joel,can you list the commands to resize the root?

Comment: At this point I am not concerned with data loss, also where should Owncloud have been installed. can you outline commands to increase Root to completion?I may re-install if this does not work. just a lot of work.

Comment: @DennisSigala That depends on the filesystem you use. Unless you use `fsadm` (I have no experience with that). But you can try `lvresize -r`.